# Are following type of questions opinion based? or unsuitable for SO

Tags: discussion

I was about ask a question, but then I hold myself, a bit confused if it qualifies as opinion based - "Why a particular function in Java return X in negative cases?". I have seen numerous questions like these, e.g. - [Why does Java's TreeSet<E> remove(Object) not take an E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015720/why-does-javas-treesete-removeobject-not-take-an-e)

They are well received, but it does ask an opinion about a library's choice of implementing requirements. Shall I still ask my question?

Comment: When they were asked is important ...

Comment: So it is opinion base. I will keep to my self, see edit

Comment: @MangatRaiModi no, this very nice example you provided is not opinion based as it does not ask for an opinion but for an explanation; it even already has factual answers as a well-known explanation actually does exist in this particular case that is part of the API specifications. Opinion based questions tend to have a form of a comparison in them, like "why is this better than that". That will definitely get an opinion-war going that has the potential to never end. I saw a question about a favorite IDE / editor on another site; 5 years later new editors were still being added to the list.

Comment: (continuing) What is almost certainly a guarantee is that the question has been asked and answered before when it comes to mature, long existing languages such as Java. That is more something to keep in mind before you ask a question, you should really double down on searching before asking.

Comment: @Thanks Gimpy, it is actually not exactly Java, but Apache Library. and the answer is nowhere...